# Setting v-select value programmatically does not fire @change in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to set v-select value programmatically, however the associated @change event does not fire. If I manually select the option, the event fires as expected.

Template:

```
<div id="app">
<v-app dark>
  <v-select 
    v-model="currentItem" 
    :items="items"
    @change="itemChanged"
  />
</v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  methods: {
    itemChanged(item) {
        console.log('item changed',item);
    }
  },
  data: {
    currentItem: '',
    items: [
        { text: "Name", value: 'name' },
      { text: "Number", value: 'number' },
      { text: "Inputs", value: 'inputs' }
    ]
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.currentItem = 'inputs';
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

The [jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/tgpfhn8m/1495/)

Does anybody have any solutions aside from manually calling the function when setting the value programmatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `change` event is defined in such a way so it is [emitted when the input is changed by user interaction (see the event documentation)](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#events). If you want to monitor all the changes, you can either use the `input` event:

```js
<v-select 
  v-model="currentItem" 
  :items="items"
  @input="itemChanged"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0qbomzta/

---

or add a watcher to ***watch*** the `currentItem`:

```js
<div id="app">
<v-app dark>
  <v-select 
    v-model="currentItem" 
    :items="items"/>
</v-app>
</div>
```

In `Vue` instance, add:

```js
watch: {
  currentItem (newVal) {
    console.log('item changed', newVal);
  }
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w5voub3h/

Comment: yes i ended up using watchers. it's not the most elegant solution, but it works

Comment: its work for me, even tho im having different problem.

i have few v-select inside v-for. when i add the provided listener :on-change. it fired on every v-select model even though i only change on one of them